# adding all js files in one file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have many js files that I reference in the head tag of my webpages. is there a way to put them all in one file (js or aspx) and reference that one file instead of referencing all the files? something instead of the below. given that I can't combine all js files in one file as every file has its own purpose

```
<script src="Scripts/js1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js4.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js5.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js6.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js7.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js8.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js9.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js10.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js11.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js12.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js13.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js14.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js16.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js17.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js15.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js18.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js19.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js20.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js23.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js24.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js25.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js26.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, then you can install Web Essentials.

http://vswebessentials.com/

After it is installed select all the JavaScript files, right click and under the Web Essentials menu select create JavaScript bundle file.

Once the bundle is created, then you only need to reference the bundled .js file. Web essentials will update the bundle if you make changes to the individual JavaScript files

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bundles](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for that and gain other features such as minification.

If you want a client side dependency framework that will do the work I would check [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a bundle and add them all at once, you can do that for you CSS as well.
This is a great video that i learned a lot from : [Scripts](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building)

Answer (score 0):

check out gruntjs, that should help you create one file to load but keep separate development files
http://gruntjs.com/

Answer (score -1):

Create a `global.js` file and add your scripts within in a self-invoked function expressions.

```
(function() {
   // codes goes here
}());
```